# Extended Riccati Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Could you help me find the general solution to the ODE bellow?

$y'(x)=y(x)/x+(7x+0.5/x). y(x)^2+(6x+1) y(x)^3$

This is somewhat an extention to the Riccati equation. I have found two particular solutions $y(x)=0$ and $y(x)=-0.5/x$, but is it possible to derive the general solution? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_equation_of_the_first_kind

Comment: @Masoud : $\:\:y(x)=-0.5/x\:$ is not a solution of $$y'(x)=y(x)/x+(7x+0.5/x). y(x)^2+(6x+1) y(x)^3$$ This is an Abel's ODE, probably not of the "solvable" kind. It would require more study to confirme. In short, is it worth it? You don't have explain what is the context and the necessity of having an explicit solution to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Let $y=\dfrac{1}{u}$ ,

Then $y'=-\dfrac{u'}{u^2}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{u'}{u^2}=\dfrac{1}{xu}+\left(7x+\dfrac{1}{2x}\right)\dfrac{1}{u^2}+\dfrac{6x+1}{u^3}$

$uu'=-\dfrac{u^2}{x}-\left(7x+\dfrac{1}{2x}\right)u-6x-1$

This belongs to an Abel equation of the second kind.

Let $u=\dfrac{v}{x}$ ,

Then $u'=\dfrac{v'}{x}-\dfrac{v}{x^2}$

$\therefore\dfrac{v}{x}\left(\dfrac{v'}{x}-\dfrac{v}{x^2}\right)=-\dfrac{v^2}{x^3}-\left(7x+\dfrac{1}{2x}\right)\dfrac{v}{x}-6x-1$

$\dfrac{vv'}{x^2}-\dfrac{v^2}{x^3}=-\dfrac{v^2}{x^3}-\left(7+\dfrac{1}{2x^2}\right)v-6x-1$

$\dfrac{vv'}{x^2}=-\left(7+\dfrac{1}{2x^2}\right)v-6x-1$

$v\dfrac{dv}{dx}=-\left(7x^2+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)v-6x^3-x^2$

Let $v=-\dfrac{w}{2}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dv}{dx}=-\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{dw}{dx}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{w}{2}\left(-\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{dw}{dx}\right)=-\left(7x^2+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\dfrac{w}{2}\right)-6x^3-x^2$

$\dfrac{w}{4}\dfrac{dw}{dx}=\left(7x^2+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\dfrac{w}{2}-6x^3-x^2$

$w\dfrac{dw}{dx}=(14x^2+1)w-24x^3-4x^2$